Videos Stop Autoplaying After Navigating Away - Barbajs
I am using barba.js for page transitions. I have video element on my corporate page that are set to autoplay, loop, and muted. Work well when I initially load the corporate page. However, when I navigate away from the corporate page and then return (without refreshing the page), the video is no longer autoplaying. The video only start autoplaying again if I manually reload the page. Note: I'm not using any frameworks (like React, Vue, etc.), just plain JavaScript (vanilla JS).
 <video loop muted autoplay>
         <source src="VIDEO_LINK" type="video/mp4">
 </video>

I re-run all my JavaScript code on every page transition with Barba.js. What should i do for the video element ?
How I can ensure the video continue autoplaying when navigating back to the page, without requiring a page reload?
Thanks in advance!

since you said you are "re-running all your js on every page transition" I suppose you are dealing with some event... can you try adding the code to play the video when such event occurs? something like document.querySelector('video').play(). It should work since it's muted but I'm not sure

Fix with adding this code block
var vids = document.querySelectorAll("video"); vids.forEach(vid => { var playPromise = vid.play(); if (playPromise !== undefined) { playPromise.then(_ => {}).catch(error => {}); }; });
Source:
https://github.com/barbajs/barba/issues/596

To ensure the video element continues to autoplay when navigating back to the page you'll need to re-trigger the autoplay attribute after each page transition. For Example:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
barba.init({
  const video = document.querySelector('video');
  if (video) {
    video.play();
  }
 });
});

